# How to map multiple values to a single item on a drop-down list and display the corresponding cell content?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm creating an Excel database with large amounts of information and i want this information to display on a "summary" sheet upon selecting a certain item on a drop-down list. For example, if i select A from the drop-down list in Sheet1, i want content from B1:B10 in Sheet2 to display in Sheet1. I tried both IF and VLOOKUP's but couldn't figure out a solution. Note that all the information is text-only and there's no such mathematical calculation involved. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Once you select "A" from sheet1, what information do you have that tells you that you should look at range B1:B10 on Sheet2 ?  ie how to you figure that out? What if you select "B" from sheet1 ?  Is the pattern consistent? C1:C10 on Sheet2 ?   B1:B10 on Sheet3 ? something else? If there's a pattern you can code it .. if there isn't, you need a lookup to map it.

Answer (score 0):

Say in *Sheet2* we have data like:

[image]

and in *Sheet1* cell **A1** we have a drop-down like:

[image]

We would like to pick a name (like David) and see all the data associated with David.

In *Sheet2* cell **C1** we enter:

```
=IF(Sheet1!$A$1="","",IF(A1=Sheet1!$A$1,1,""))
```

and in cell **C2** we enter:

```
=IF(Sheet1!$A$1="","",IF(A2=Sheet1!$A$1,1+MAX($C$1:C1),""))
```

and copy this downwards.  Column **C** will mark the rows of interest.  If we pick David in *Sheet1,* *Sheet2* now looks like:

[image]

Now all we have to do is gather the items of interest.  In *Sheet1* cell **A2** we enter:

```
=IF(ROWS($1:1)>MAX(Sheet2!C:C),"",INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),Sheet2!C:C)))
```

and copy down.  *Sheet1* now displays:

[image]